# Which is better CachingConnectionFactory.CacheMode Connection or Channel in Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Hi I have been using Spring AMQP with connection obtained from CachingConnectionFactory with the properties being shown below

```
<bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="rabbit-server-fqdn" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="some-vhost" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password " />
   <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25" />
</bean>
```

Now i need to change my mode to Connection as i need to check open connection

```
   <bean id="connectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg value="rabbit-server-fqdn" />
    <property name="virtualHost" value="some-vhost" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password " />
    <property name="cacheMode" value="CONNECTION" />
   <property name="channelCacheSize" value="25" />
</bean>
```

So 
Q1. Will channelCacheSize will work ? 
Q2. what will be default connection pool size in CachingConnectionFactory ?
Q3. Do i need to set additional property ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CHANNEL` is better, because you don't need to create a new connection for each call, but reuse a shared one.

The [Reference Manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#connections) has plenty of facts on the matter. One of them is when do you really need `CONNECTION` mode:

> The use of separate connections might be useful in some environments, such as consuming from an HA cluster, in conjunction with a load balancer, to connect to different cluster members.

The shared connection is still can be traced for open/close state via `ConnectionListener` injected into that `CachingConnectionFactory`.

Comment: When using `cacheMode=CONNECTION`, the pool will grow unbounded as needed; there is no limit by default; you can set a limit with `connectionLimit`. In that mode, the channel cache is per-connection. But, in most cases, there will only be one cached channel per connection.

Comment: @artem, any idea for what actuve field is used in cachingconnectionfactory

Comment: Sorry, the question isn’t not clear. Maybe separate SO thread?